# Local DNS in a standard DHCP LAN

Tags: dns, bonjour, lan, dhcp

Our customers are typical broadband home users, with a DSL Modem/Router which offers DHCP.
We want our device which is connected to the home LAN and has an embedded HTTP Server to be addressable with a domain name (www.mydevice.ip or something). In particular, we want to avoid that the user has to get the IP address and type it into the address bar of his browser.

What solutions are available?

Has the typical DHCP Modem a DNS included - how do you use it?

Could other services offer help (eg. Bonjour)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mDNS/DNS-SD using "avahi" daemon -- this should work on mac + linux hosts, and maybe for windows.

For Windows, you can set up SAMBA to get WINS name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

A "typical DHCP Modem" is no standard so there is no default answer.

What you want, is that the modem works as a DNS cache (which is pretty much the default) and additionally add your own, static DNS entries that point to the IP of the entry.

How you achieve that depends on the router...